# Removing Hotkeys

Tags: add-on

Is there a way to remove all the hotkeys?

I've used 3D max for around 6-7 years, over that course of time I had my own arsenal of personal hotkeys(shortcuts).
I've decided to move over to Blender, I'm trying to rebuild my little infrastructure but hotkeys are conflicting, I don't want to delete blenders hotkeys, one by one.

Any idea how I can get a clean slate, and just rebuild from there?

Answer (score 1):

Do you tried Industry Compatible keymap?

This one ships with lasted builds from builder.blender.org and includes key-buildings most popular in outer programs (like max,maya,houdini ets.)

In last builds you can turn it on in Edit -> Preferences -> Keymap

[image]